# Simplify nested loop python

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have two big lists called a and b. Both of them have a size of 2000 values. Each value is DataFrame with 35136 values.

```
a = [Dataframe, Dataframe....] --> Size:2000
a[0] = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0....] -->Name: colA, Size:35136
.
.
a[8] = []
.
.
b = [Dataframe, Dataframe....]
b[0] = [11, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 11.....] -->Name: colB, Size:35136
```

I need to change the DataFrame a iterating in both lists and in each DataFrame. How to do it faster?

```
for j in range(0, 2000):
    for i in range(0, 35136):
        if len(a[j]) == 0:
           b[j] = []
        else:
           if b[j]['colA'][i] != 0:
               tmp = b[j]['colA'][i]
           if (b[j]['colA'][i] == 0) & (a[j]['colB'][i] == 0):
              b[j]['colA'][i] = tmp
```

Desired output is for this input:

```
b[0] = [11, 11, 11, 0, 50, 50, 0, 11.....] -->Name: colB, Size:35136
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal example of input data so we could easily run and test the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example, I think this should be equivalent (and significantly faster):

```
for idx, (df_a, df_b) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    if len(df_a) == 0:
       b[idx] = []
    else:
       df_b['colA'].mask(cond=(df_b['colA'] == 0) & (df_a['colB'] == 0), 
                         other=df_b['colA'].where(df_b['colA'] != 0).ffill(),
                         inplace=True)
```

This relies on all of the DataFrames having the same index (not just the same size), which will be the default unless you've set your own indices.